# Google bubble chart on data change error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, bubble-chart

I am using Google's BubbleChart using directive 'https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart'

Whenever i try changing the data in controller or resize the window the chart gives and error **Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined**

I have tried to redraw the chart by manually firing the **$rootScope.$emit('resizeMsg');**

but it is not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using

```
animation
```

with bubble chart it might give error on draw or redraw, that's why you get the error.

remove the animation and try again.

Comment: thanks it works just fine after removing the animation